# What is equivalent of spyOn.and.callFake in Sinon?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jasmine, sinon

How do I write a spy that callsFake in Sinon, similar to Jasmine?

Jasmine:

```
spyOn(window, "requestAnimationFrame").and.callFake(() => {});
```

Sinon:

```
// pseudo code
const requestAnimationFrameSpy = spy().and.callFake(() => {}); 
global.window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrameSpy;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this a couple different ways, either with [sinon fakes](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v5.1.0/fakes/) similar to:

```
const requestAnimationFrameSpy = sinon.fake().returns({value:'some value'}); 
global.window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrameSpy();
```

You can also do this with [sinon stubs](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.0.0/stubs/):

```
//from sinon website
var myObj = {};
myObj.prop = function propFn() {
    return 'foo';
};

sinon.stub(myObj, 'prop').callsFake(function fakeFn() {
    return 'bar';
});

myObj.prop(); // 'bar'
```